# Taping on mkpinannotationview

Tags: iphone

I want to navigate to next class through tap on mkpinannotationview. How can i do this plz give some sample code for this.
Thanks sandy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mapView delegate will be called when the pin is selected.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
 // Here push your view controller
}
```

Comment: - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
  BusinessCardViewController *businessCardViewController=[[BusinessCardViewController alloc]init];
     [self.view addSubview:businessCardViewController.view];

}

Comment: But still nothing happened and also i am using the delegate in .h class

Comment: - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {  BusinessCardViewController *businessCardViewController=[[BusinessCardViewController alloc]init];  [self presentModalViewController:businessCardViewController animated:YES]; [release businessCardViewController];

Comment: See this http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/